# How can I automatically delete log files in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I have QuestDB running with debug logging enabled and the log file grows very quickly, it adds few GB per day. How can I set it up so that it doesn't keep more than X GB or X days of logs?

I have considered doing a bash script to split the log file but I don't think it's a good idea to try deleting from the file while the DB is writing into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change logging configuration as described in

https://questdb.io/docs/reference/configuration/#configuration-file

and used `LogRollingFileWriter`:

```
# list of configured writers
writers=file,stdout
# file writer
w.file.class=io.questdb.log.LogRollingFileWriter
w.file.location=log/questdb-debug-info-error.log
w.file.level=DEBUG,INFO,ERROR
w.file.rollSize=100m
```

This will start rolling log file after every 100 Mb to a new file. You can then automate archiving or deleting unwanted log files.

Rolling can be by size (as above) or by time. To get rolling by day use

```
w.file.rollEvery=DAY
```

Day, Month, Year, Hour and Minute values are supported.

This all from here https://github.com/questdb/questdb/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/questdb/log/LogRollingFileWriter.java, not documented properly

Answer (score 1):

Since QuestDB 6.7, `LogRollingFileWriter` supports `lifeDuration` and `sizeLimit` log file auto-deletion parameters, so there is no more need for a separate cron job / process to delete the old files.

```
# rolling file writer 
#w.file.class=io.questdb.log.LogRollingFileWriter
#w.file.location=${log.dir}/questdb-rolling.log.${date:yyyyMMdd}
#w.file.level=INFO,ERROR
#rollEvery accepts: day, hour, minute, month
#w.file.rollEvery=day
#rollSize specifies size at which to roll a new log file: a number followed by k, m, g (KB, MB, GB respectively)
#w.file.rollSize=128m
#lifeDuration accepts: a number followed by s, m, h, d, w, M, y for seconds, minutes, hours, etc.  
#w.file.lifeDuration=1d
#sizeLimit is the max fileSize of the log directory. Follows same format as rollSize
#w.file.sizeLimit=1g
```